# How to provide nested folder path in testcafe commandline?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm unable to provide nested directory path in testcafe command line

I have created different directories under the test folder to consolidate different type of test

Example: I have folder "BVT" and "UnitTest" under test folder

- Test -> BVT
- Test -> UnitTest

To run only BVT test, I'm using below command to provide nest folder path but testcafe unable to find under sub-directory

Example: testcafe chrome /test/btv/

Error: "ERROR No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive."

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a dot indicating the current directory. You can also omit the trailing slash as it is redundant:

```
testcafe chrome ./test/bvt
```

Your path specifies the folder located in the root.